# Script that logs chat data from Twitch.tv

Tags: python

I am looking to get some feedback on **Python 3.6**+ project. Specifically I'm looking to improve my skills and make myself a more attractive prospective employee. I plan to use my Github repo(s) as a demonstration of my skills and knowledge.

Summary:

It's a 'bot' which connects to the Twitch.tv IRC, retrieves a list of the top streamers from the Twitch API, joins their chat channel, and logs the messages sent by users. It should be completely PEP8 complaint aside from the line lengths. Do you believe it's critical to adhere to the line length, I was seeing mixed opinions of 'yes absolutely' and 'no just make sure it's consistent and readable'?

[Github repo](https://github.com/disabledtech/Twitch-IRC-Logger)

**twitch_irc_bot.py**

```
import socket
import time
import requests
from codecs import decode
import os

import logging
import logging.handlers

logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

# Set our logger's time format to UTC
logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime

# Where logs will be stored.
logs_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logs/')

# Make the folder if it does not exist.
if not os.path.exists(logs_folder):
    os.mkdir(logs_folder)

# Set up the logger. Log files will rotated saved every 10 minutes.
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s — %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(logs_folder + 'chat.log',   # Active log name
                                                                        when='M',
                                                                        interval=10,  # Log rotation in min.
                                                                        encoding='utf-8')])


class TwitchBot(object):
    """
    A bot which joins multiple Twitch IRC channels and records
    their messages to a rotating log file. The channels it joins
    are from a list of the streams with the most current viewers
    retrieved from the Twitch API. The number of streams to log
    can be configured up to a max. of 100.
    """

    def __init__(self, username, token, client_id, game='', refresh_interval=60, limit=25):
        """
        Initializes TwitchBot

        :param username:    What the bot will call itself when joining the IRC server. Do not use the same
                            name as a popular streamer, it will break the script.
        :param token:       The OAuth token used to join the Twitch IRC.
        :param client_id:   The client_id of your Twitch dev. application. See: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5
        :param game:        The game that you want all streams to be playing. e.g. 'Overwatch'. Default: Any game ('').
        :param refresh_interval: How often (in seconds) to call __update() and get a new list of top streams. Default: 60
        :param limit:       The maximum numbers of streams to join. Default: 25 Max: 100
        """

        self.__server = 'irc.chat.twitch.tv'  # Twitch IRC IP Address
        self.__port = 6667                    # Twitch IRC Port
        self.username = username
        self.token = token
        self.client_id = client_id

        self.refresh_interval = refresh_interval
        self.game = game
        self.limit = limit

        # Get an initial list of streams.
        self.channel_list = self.__get_top_streamers()

        # Connect to the Twitch IRC.
        self.__connect()

    def __connect(self):
        """
        Connect to the twitch.tv IRC server and then JOIN each IRC channel in self.channel_list

        :return: None
        """

        self.sock_connection = socket.socket()
        self.sock_connection.connect((self.__server, self.__port))

        self.sock_connection.send('PASS {}\n'.format(self.token).encode('utf-8'))
        self.sock_connection.send('NICK {}\n'.format(self.username).encode('utf-8'))

        # Call __join_channel() for all channels in the channel_list
        for channel in self.channel_list:

            self.__join_channel(channel)

    def __join_channel(self, channel):
        """
        Joins the specified twitch.tv IRC channel
        :param channel: The twitch.tv IRC channel to join. Usually (always?) the caster's channel name.

        :return: None
        """

        self.sock_connection.send('JOIN #{}\n'.format(channel).encode('utf-8'))

    def __leave_channel(self, channel):
        """
        Leaves the specified twitch.tv IRC channel
        :param channel: The twitch.tv IRC channel to leave. Usually (always?) the caster's channel name.

        :return: None
        """

        self.sock_connection.send('PART {}\n'.format(channel).encode('utf-8'))

    def __update(self):
        """
        Updates which channels we're logging. Fetches a new list of
        streams from __get_top_streamers() and compares it with our current
        list of streams. Compares the lists to get which streams have
        entered/left the top 100. Calls __leave_channel/__join_channel on
        these lists as needed.

        :return: None
        """

        new_channels = self.__get_top_streamers()
        old_channels = self.channel_list

        # Compares the stream lists to find which streams to join/leave.
        channels_to_leave = list(set(old_channels) - set(new_channels))
        channels_to_join = list(set(new_channels) - set(old_channels))

        # Leave streams in not in top 100
        for channel in channels_to_leave:

            self.__leave_channel(channel)

        # Join streams new to the top 100
        for channel in channels_to_join:

            self.__join_channel(channel)

        # Update the list of channels we're currently in.
        self.channel_list = new_channels

    def __get_top_streamers(self):
        """
        Gets the 100 channels with the most current viewers. Uses the param
        settings from initialization (self.game, self.limit) to determine
        which and how many streams to grab.

        :return: A list of channels in the top *self.limit* system currently.
        """

        # Parameters for the Twitch API request
        twitch_api_params = {
            'client_id': self.client_id,    # Required
            'api_version': 5,               # Required
            'game': self.game,              # Optional
            'limit': self.limit             # Optional, defaults to 25. Max is 100.
        }

        names = []

        # Request the JSON data from twitch.
        channel_list = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/',
                                    params=twitch_api_params).json()

        # Extract channel names from the JSON data.
        for name in channel_list['streams']:
            names.append(name['channel']['name'])

        return names

    def __close_connection(self):
        """
        Close our socket connection.

        :return:
        """
        print('Exiting...')

        self.sock_connection.close()

        exit(0)

    def __log_message(self, response):
        """
        Save a valid message to your logs. A valid message is one that is
        NOT a PING from the server, IS greater than 0 in length, and
        does NOT contain our own name (such as those from the IRC
        server when we first join). Choosing the same *username* for
        the bot as a popular streamer will probably (100%) break the
        logging for said streamer's channel at best. I have no idea
        what a worst-case-scenario would be (disabled for 'impersonation'?).
        Investigate at your own discretion.

        :param response: A single message response from the server.
        :return:
        """

        # Send a PONG if the server sends a PING
        if response.startswith('PING'):

            self.sock_connection.send('PONG\n'.encode('utf-8'))

        elif len(response) > 0 and self.username not in response:

            logging.info(response.rstrip('\r\r\n'))

    def run(self):
        """
        Run the script until user interruption.

        :return: None
        """

        # A flag used to determine if it'stime to call __update().
        top_100_check = time.time()

        while True:

            try:

                # Get response from the IRC server
                try:

                    response = decode(self.sock_connection.recv(2048), encoding='utf-8')

                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    # TODO Handle this better
                    # Sometimes this exception is raised, however it happens extremely
                    # rarely (< ~0.1%) and is not significant unless it is absolutely critical
                    # you do not miss anything. At the moment we simply skip over these errors.
                    continue

                # Sometimes in a busy channel many messages are received
                # in one 'response' and we need to split them apart. See
                # https://stackoverflow.com/q/28859961 for a longer and
                # more detailed explanation by someone else with the
                # same issue.
                #
                # All message end with '\r\n' so we can reliably count/split
                # them this way.

                line_count = response.count("\r\n")

                if line_count > 1:

                    messages = response.split("\r\n")

                    for single_msg in messages:

                        self.__log_message(single_msg)

                else:

                    self.__log_message(response)

                # Check if the time now is more than the refresh_interval + the
                # last time we checked the top 100.
                if time.time() > top_100_check + self.refresh_interval:

                    # Update the time we last checked to now.
                    top_100_check = time.time()

                    # Update our channel list.
                    self.__update()

            # Shut down 'gracefully' on keyboard interrupt.
            except KeyboardInterrupt:

                self.__close_connection()
```

**run_bot.py**

```
from twitch_irc_bot import TwitchBot
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os


def main():

    config = ConfigParser()

    # Try to find the config file, if it does not exist, create one.
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini')):

        print("Config file not found. Creating one...")

        __create_config(config)

        print("Config file created. Please fill out the settings.")

        exit(0)

    config.read('config.ini')

    username = config['TWITCH_BOT_SETTINGS']['username']
    token = config['TWITCH_BOT_SETTINGS']['token']
    client_id = config['TWITCH_BOT_SETTINGS']['client_id']
    channel_limit = config['TWITCH_BOT_SETTINGS'].getint('channel_limit')


    # Initialize bot.
    bot = TwitchBot(username=username,
                    token=token,
                    client_id=client_id,
                    limit=channel_limit)

    # Runs the bot until user interrupts it.
    bot.run()


def __create_config(config):
    """
    Creates a fresh config file with the needed parameters.

    :param config: a ConfigParser() object.
    """

    config['TWITCH_BOT_SETTINGS'] = {'username': '',
                                     'token': '',
                                     'client_id': '',
                                     'channel_limit': ''}

    with open('config.ini', 'w') as new_config_files:

        config.write(new_config_files)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**config.ini**

```
[TWITCH_BOT_SETTINGS]
username = 
token = 
client_id = 
channel_limit =
```

Thanks for your time everyone, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, just to tell you, I guess your Github repo is *private* so the link you provided result in a 404 error.

Comment: To simply react to one of your first question, one of the first statement of PEP8 boils down to "these are not hard rules, if you need/want to deviate, just make sure it's consistent and readable". That being said, PEP8 compliant code looks more like Python than others.

Comment: Thanks, Ced. It was private, fixed it now.

Thanks for your input, Mathias, that makes sense.